# Anyone using Amazon EC2 + SQL Azure?

Tags: .net, sql, azure, amazon-ec2

Anyone running any .NET web apps on Amazon EC2 but using SQL Azure for their RDBMS?

I can't see why this wouldn't work but I was wondering if anyone has any experiences good or bad.

Comment: Why would you do this? If your web app is hosting in ec2 and your database is in azure, you're probably sending db request miles away from your app. Bad for performance

Comment: @ShawnMclean: actually even an Azure-to-SQL-Azure request takes of the order of ~150 milliseconds round trip. If you choose your configuration carefully and make sure you're using servers in the same geography on both sides there's no reason why the heterogenous mix shouldn't give about the same performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are actually doing the opposite of this. Our SQL Server is in EC2 but web server on Azure. I know it sounds odd, but we did it because we already had servers in EC2 but we get a certain amount of free Azure hours per month with BizSpark.

Anyway, it is working very well. We just had to open the firewall in EC2 to allow the Azure IP address through. We havnt noticed any performance issues.

Comment: This indeed can work, but only if you don't care about the time it takes to obtain the requested data.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - Actually, I just ran a test for Amazon EC2 (Ireland), and Azure (Ireland). For a simple count on one of my tables, running the query from EC2 takes 60-65ms per query. Running the exact same query from an Azure instance takes 70-80ms per query. Hence, you are only really adding 10-15ms per db query - which for most scenarios won't be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

I do this for several clients.  It works quite well.  If Amazon had SQL Server rather than Oracle or MySQL I'd be using that, but my apps are all T-SQL.

In either case, the time between Microsoft and Amazon is practically nill.  Remember, if you are programming correctly, their is very little back-and-forth. Cost wise, you can get a nice fast Azure database for $50/month that will never break.  You get an amazon EC2 server for about $50/month.  You get an S3 bucket for your static files and a cloud-front link to join them with your site - cost $5/month.

Bam. If you want to scale up, just copy that EC2 instance and use their load balancer.  Boom.  No down time.  No screwing around with databases.  It just goes.

Oh yeah... if your client wants the site, they can just pop it on their own machine wherever they want, change the DNS and you can sign the Azure DB over to them. No downtime.

Anyway, Amazon rocks.  Azure is pretty nice.  For financial reasons, I actually use Azure for all my DB, cloudfront for all static files, and colocated servers at Hurricane Electric for my own  webservers.  If they go down (as they actually did today for 20 mins), it automatically fails-over to an EC2 machine which can still reach the data at Azure, so nobody really notices.